# Unwanted space around hline introduces gaps in the table

Tags: tables, spacing, hline, gap

I am using a latex template of a journal on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/agu-official#.WBukk-ErLus) to prepare an article. The template adds spaces around the `\hline` so that the following code:

```
\documentclass[draft]{agujournal2019}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Table Name}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
 Run  & Time (min)  \\
\hline
  $l1$  & 260   \\
  $l2$  & 300   \\
  $l3$  & 340   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

produces a table with broken borders:

[image]

So far I could not find a way to make the borders solid and I will appreciate any advice.

Edit: extended the code sample

Comment: Does your class/file load `booktabs`? (we cannot say, because you didn't post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)). If yes, vertical lines and booktabs  are not compatible. Remove them.

Comment: @Rmano booktabs on its own wouldn't do that, there must be also some redefinition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class you are using has

```
  %% This puts extra space between horizontal lines in tables.
  %% If you want to use vertical lines in tables, you should use
  %% \savehline rather than \hline, otherwise the vertical and
  %% horizontal lines will not abutt.

  %% \noalign is a command that allows the uses to put something
  %% between lines in a table.
\let\savehline\hline
\def\hline{\noalign{\vskip3pt}\savehline\noalign{\vskip3pt}}
```

So use `\savehline` or (better) don't use vertical rules.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem without any conflicting packages installed or any personal definitions, the solution was to use the `\hhline` package. it's a little more work to define an horizontal style for each column, but the interaction with vertical lines works better. for standard tables you can just use `\hhline{-----}` with a dash for each column.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).